# Recreate NCL bin_avg function in python

Tags: python, binning, ncl

I am trying to recreate NCL's [bin_avg](https://www.ncl.ucar.edu/Document/Functions/Built-in/bin_avg.shtml) function in python. The function takes in a list of latitudes, longitudes, and observation values at those points, and calculates the average value of the observations contained within each box in some grid.

The closest I could come up with is using `scipy.spatial.cKDTree.query_ball_point`, but this finds all points within a radisu rather than within a grid box...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like what I was looking for is in `scipy.stats.binned_statistic`